# Why is React app not momentum scrolling div on iOS?

Tags: ios, reactjs, scroll, webkit

I have an app I build in React that has a `div` with `overflow: scroll`. On Chrome in MacOS, the `div` momentum/inertia scrolls, but on iOS, it stops scrolling as soon as you lift your finger. What could cause this?